# Delete Database using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.7, error-000601

I used the ModelBuilder to create a module that can automatically create a database to store the intermediate outputs and save the final output (one shapefile) in a folder. User can choose which folder to store the final output and the database will be created within that folder too. To avoid any confusions or overwrite issues, I'd like this module to automatically delete the database after the final output being generated. So I added the "Delete" function and used the final output as the precondition. However, it leads to an ERROR 000601 that saying the database may be locked by another application so it can't be deleted. I'm wondering if there is anyway that I could run the "delete" database function in the same module that creates the database.

[image: Error Message]
[image: Module]
[image: Module Input]

Comment: You need to delete any other objects that have linked to the data in your geodatabase. You have several sub-models in your model that you do not explain what happens in them. The construction of any featurelayer used in a spatial selection for example will likely hold onto locks in the geodatabase.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I added a picture of the user interface of the module. It shows all the inputs. The database and final output will be saved in the "Output Folder" that user chooses. All the submodules process/create intermediate outputs in the database. The last module first generates the final output (a shapefile) in the database, then exports it into the "Output Folder" using the "Copy Feature" function.